# My PHP Manual Examples Are Tiny

Tags: php, help-files

The example code in the PHP manuals that I downloaded recently (June 2019 and Sept? 2018) are so tiny that I cannot read them.
The 2009 manual is fine.

What could be the problem?

See attached screenshot:[Help file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhHIL.jpg)

Comment: What Internet Explorer (mshtml) version is installed on this system?

Comment: @grawity If you mean the browser, it is Version 8.0.6.
If you mean something else, please tell me where to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

1. Open PHP Manual CHM file
2. Go to *Options > Internet Options > General Tab*
3. Click on the *Accessibility* button
4. Check the option of "Ignore font sizes specified on webpages"
5. Press OK.

Note that this may have effect on the display of web-pages in Internet Explorer,
but you may undo it when not reading the manual.